# Detect null QUuid from QML

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have a `QUuid` property in a C++ class that is exposed to QML, and sometimes the `QUuid` value can be null (i.e. `QUuid::isNull() == true`).  However the only way I have found to detect this state from QML is to implicitly convert it to a `String` first:

```
if ( proxy.interpolatorID != "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" ) {
    ...
}
```

Which is pretty ugly.  Using the `typeof` operator, the `QUuid` is specified as an `object`, but if I use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( proxy.interpolatorID )` to list all of the properties and functions, an empty list is returned.

In desperation I also tried `!!proxy.interpolatorID`, but it returns true regardless of the actual numerical value (unsurprisingly).

So what exactly *is* a `QUuid` in QML?  And can I do anything more elegant for null detection instead of `String` conversion or adding another property to my C++ class providing the null state?

Comment: QML documentation doesn't explicitly list `QUuid` as a supported type when passing data between C++ and QML, so you're likely depending on something that's not quite fully implemented. You'll probably need to add your own bridge for that type. My hunch, without looking at the code, is that there's some support for types with `toString` methods that are also constructible from strings. On the javascript side, you have only a string, perhaps an unboxed one, not a UUID.

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, I suspect you're right.